# Angular 2 material autocomplete selected value

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, selectedvalue

I have autocomplete input

```
<div formArrayName="addresses"> 
  <div class="row" 
       *ngFor="let itemrow of searchForm.controls.addresses.controls; let i=index" 
       [formGroupName]="i">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" 
             class="form-control" id="address"
             formControlName="address" 
             matInput 
             [matAutocomplete]="auto"
             (keyup)="getESRI($event.target.value)"
             (focusout)="bindLocation($event.target.value)">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of testLocation"
                    [value]="option.text">
           {{ option.text }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field> 
  </div>
</div>
```

`"testlocation":[{"text":"Euronet","magicKey":"dHA9MSNubT1FdXJvbmV0I2NzPTE5OjExI3NjPURFVQ==","isCollection":true},{"text":"Euronet","magicKey":"dHA9MSNubT1FdXJvbmV0I2NzPTE5OjExI3NjPURFVQ==","isCollection":true}]`

When I'm trying add value `[value]="option.magicKey` it shows in the input `option.magicKey` when I select option. I need `option.magicKey` only as the value, and `option.text` as the input option. Otherwise how to add `option.magicKey` as parameter to `bindLocation($event.target.value)` function?

Answer (score 11):

## Use 'displayWith'

MatAutoComplete features an input called `displayWith`. Therein, you need to pass a function that maps your option's control value to its display value.

### Here is an example:

```
<mat-form-field>

  <input
    matInput
    placeholder="Select a value"
    [formControl]="form.controls.enumField"
    [matAutocomplete]="autoComplete">

  <mat-autocomplete
    #autoComplete="matAutocomplete"
    [displayWith]="valueMapper">     <-- Using displayWith here

  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let enum of enumerationObservable | async"
    [value]="enum.key">
      {{ enum.value }}
  </mat-option>

</mat-autocomplete>
```

**Here's the function that returns value using key received**

```
public valueMapper = (key) => {
  let selection = this.enumeration.find(e => e.key === key);
  if (selection)
    return selection.value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[displayWith]** attribute with auto complete field.

HTML FILE

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Address"
  mdInput
  formControlName="address" 
  [mdAutocomplete]="auto"
  (keyup)="onKeyUp()">
<md-autocomplete
  #auto="mdAutocomplete"
  [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <md-option *ngFor="let option of options"
    [value]="option">
    {{ option.text }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: But how to get option.magicKey value? Can I call another function with option.magicKey argument inside displayFn(option) function? Or how I can pass option.magicKey value to (focusout) event ?

Comment: Pass option where you want to pass it and then fetch magicKey from it. Simple.

Comment: Problem is address inside formArray

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am found solution

Comment: How can update the search term with the keydown option value? NOT upon selecting.

Answer (score 0):

`<mat-option>` has event **onSelectionChange**, with this event you can call any function and bind everything from option object

```
(onSelectionChange)="bindLocation(option.text, option.magicKey)"
```